# Broadcast an object with MPI

Tags: object, mpi, broadcast

Is there a way to broadcast an object or will I have to bcast all of the values it contains some other way?

Comment: What is the object? Does it contain only POD (int, char, float) and no pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume C++ language as only language having objects and defined MPI interface in standard. If I wrong, just say. For other languages basic principle is like this.

Basically, if you can do a memcpy of the object or store it into file (`write`) and read it from the file (`read`), you can do an MPI_Bcast of the memory, in which object is stored.

To be able of doing this, your object should

- be composed with Only POD types (plain old data: char, int, float, double) or other objects with the same property
- have no pointers inside it, because after sending to another MPI process, memory will be not the same as in sending process.

If your object is more complex, it should be serialized (marshalled) to some buffer before sending and deserialized (unmarshalled) after receive. You can use [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) - but even this variant is not universal (there are limits on how object can be organized to be serializable)

PS boost serialization is integrated into [`Boost.MPI`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/mpi.html)